# import certificate with password

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, certificate

this code import cert successfully, but with old password.

```
                guard let secCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, certData) else {
                     completion(false)
                     return
                }
                var query: [String: Any] = [
                    kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                    kSecValueRef as String: secCert,
                    kSecAttrLabel as String: alias,
                ]
                SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
                var addStatus: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
```

I need to change cert password before SecItemAdd. I tried add to query:

```
query[kSecImportExportPassphrase as String] = newPassword
```

but its return -50.

Can you help me, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I checked if password match via PKCS12import and than create a new p12 file with new password. After this I imported the cert to keychain.